# can we pass jvm arguments to AWS lambda function having Java runtime using CloudFormation template

Tags: java, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, jvm-arguments

Can we pass jvm arguments to AWS Lambda function?

If yes, Do we have any option to pass the jvm arguments using CloudFormation Template to our AWS Lambda Function?

Comment: Do you have any example template demonstrating what you want to do?

Comment: No Marcin. I want to have the below attribute as jvm argument to our lambda. 
JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: '-Djdk.attach.allowAttachSelf=true'

I'm not sure how to pass the jvm arguments either using console or cloudformation template.